# Serialize date to url safe string in Python

Tags: python, string, datetime, date, serialization

I'd like to serialize a Date in python to a URL Safe string.

I remember in C++, I used to just take the integer representing the number of seconds since January 1st 1970 (or something like that).  Then I could turn it into a Base64 url-safe string.  C++ dates were designed to be able to pass these integers around easily.

Ideally in Python, I'd like to get a byte array representing the date, then pass that to base64.urlsafe_b64encode().  Then when I wanted to de-serialize, I could de-encode the bytes and pass it back into a datetime object.  I do not see how to do this in Python though.

I believe I could use datetime.isoformat(), but the string produced by that seems to be unnecessarily long and I do not need it to be human readable.  I could also write custom functions to do the translation, but I'd like to use official library code if possible.

Am I missing something?  is there an "easy" way to do this that I am not seeing?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Alright, so this is what I settled on.  It is a variant of what @bgporter suggested below.  My goal was to turn the datetime information into a url-safe string without taking up too much unnecessary space so I modified the code such that the bytes from the "int" timestamp are being directly base64 url-encoded as opposed to translated into a string of digits (which don't need to be base64 url-encoded).  The resulting timestamp is about 8 characters and looks like this: `a7NaTw==`:

Encode timestamp (url-safe Base64 string):

```
url_safe_timestamp = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(struct.pack('L', int(time.time())))
```

Decode timestamp (Date object):

```
decoded_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(struct.unpack('L', base64.urlsafe_b64decode(url_safe_timestamp))[0]))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
>>> import base64
>>> import time
>>> encoded = base64.urlsafe_b64encode("%d" % int(time.time()))
>>> print encoded
'MTMzMTMyOTE5NA=='
>>> decoded = int(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encoded))
>>> print decoded
1331329194
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(decoded)   
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 9, 16, 39, 54)
```

?

(and I'm not sure why base 64 encoding here is better than just using a hex value -- what am I missing?)

Comment: The objective of the Base64 was to keep the information compressed.  A hex value is uses string characters to represent a value in base 16.  With base 64, the information is a little more compressed.  Although looking over this code, you first turned the "int" from the timestamp into a base 10 string (just regular characters representing digits).  This is probably compressed enough and also makes it possible for a developer to eyeball which timestamps came earlier and later.  When you translated from a base 10 string into a base 64, I think the string actually became longer.

Comment: Base64 is not a compression.  It's a way of taking and 8 bit byte array and turning it into a 7 bit array, which appears to be Ascii.  This necessarily causes the result to be more bytes than the original (opposite of compression).  It's a radix-64 representation.  Anytime you want a binary to be saved in an ascii file, use base64.  See Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Note that base64 uses `=` to pad the string to a multiple of three, and that `=` is not a URL-safe character.

Answer (score 0):

```
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
print(
    urlsafe_b64encode(
        bytes.fromhex(
            hex(int(time() * 1000)).lstrip('0x').rjust(12, '0')
        )
    ).decode('ascii').rstrip('=')
)

# prints: AWkLDNvo
```